# ideas for propagating Option or Result to C code

Tags: rust

Writing a big library that will be called from C# via c interop. Trying to get a nice clean interface right from the start.

I wonder if anybody has ideas for propagating Option or Result to c callers. I like the rust way and would like to carry those semantics over if possible.

Comment: you could return an union and a discriminant inside a structure, implementing enum manually

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment by Stargateur you can use some `repr(C)` struct and union combinations. Due to some limitations on `union` we require the underlying types to implement `Copy`.

```
#[repr(C)]
union COptionEnum<T>
where
    T: Copy,
{
    value: T,
    none: (),
}

#[repr(C)]
struct COption<T>
where
    T: Copy,
{
    discriminant: u32,
    value: COptionEnum<T>,
}
```

However these are not particularly ergonomic, so to ease the pain, you can provide conversions to and from `Option`. These look like this:

```
impl<T> From<Option<T>> for COption<T>
where
    T: Copy,
{
    fn from(v: Option<T>) -> COption<T> {
        match v {
            None => COption {
                discriminant: 0,
                value: COptionEnum { none: () },
            },
            Some(v) => COption {
                discriminant: 1,
                value: COptionEnum { value: v },
            },
        }
    }
}

impl<T> From<COption<T>> for Option<T>
where
    T: Copy,
{
    fn from(v: COption<T>) -> Option<T> {
        match v.discriminant {
            0 => None,
            1 => Some(unsafe { v.value.value }),
            _ => panic!("Invalid COption"),
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you can use these in a relatively painless manner.

```
#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct AType {
    a: i32,
    b: u64,
}

fn main() {
    let v1 = Some(AType { a: 1, b: 2 });
    let cv1: COption<AType> = v1.into();
    let w1: Option<AType> = cv1.into();
}
```

A complete copy is in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=45137ff322514b6a75c75eb1feb4bec4)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think unit type is possible to represent in C. I don't know how C# handle C call but unless C# also have a way to represent unit type like Rust does and also to express it as a C union I'm not sure this is possible. (also I wonder why this code doesn't generate a warning about that)

Comment: ‘Unit type’ - what’s that?

Comment: I don’t think this is usable - you cannot no_mangle generics

Comment: Youn can't no-mangle a generic, but you may not be able to no-mangle it, but that doesn't mean you can't pass it to C. Or at least pass a pointer to it to C which you can use there. 

Should you want to actually pass the object I think you can add no-mangle to a `#repr(transparent)` wrapper struct.

Comment: You can see a compiling version of the `#[repr(transparent)]` version here https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=faf43bc6c0da329d4c0f0b7e67c7f23e